# Keep only n entities in a datastore model - App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an ndb Model that looks like this:

```
class Post(ndb.Model):
   time   = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
   body   = ndb.TextProperty()
```

And I am only interested in storing N Posts.
So if I already have N Post entities and I add a new entity I want to remove the oldest Post (based on DateTime) so that the new one is added and the total number of entites is still N; something like a circular queue.

What is the most effecient way to do this? I can think of two ways:

1) Handle this on inserting, so fetch entities with an offset of N-1 (result should only be one entity) and remove that and then insert the new entity (or order by time ascendingly and grab the first one).

2) Handle this in a cronjob, so every 24 hours fetch entities with an offset of N and remove all of them.

And there is of course the option of just leaving them there..
I will not use more than N entities but I'm guessing removing entities could be expensive so I could just do a fetch(N) every time I retrieve posts and order by time descendingly.

The whole point of this is to do something cheap so I don't waste resources.

EDIT:
I'm predicting N would probably be around 100-300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not mention your expected qps volume, but the "every 24 hours" cron job suggests low-to-moderate. You also do not say if N=100 or N=10,000. If not high-volume transactional, then this can be pretty easily handled by a pull queue launched by a regularly scheduled cron - something like every few minutes. You need a second entity to keep track of the last id number used. The pull queue task would simple read the last entity id number used (let's say these range from 100-199 for N=100). Lease the tasks and work through them creating a list of new ids for your new (replacement) entities. Very simple to do. Once you have worked through the leased tasks, do a multiple put(). I can not say for sure about what the effective limit is on a multi put(), but have had no problem doing several hundred at a time using small-sized entities like yours. If you are talking N=10,000, then I would still do it this way, but you need to iterate through the lease tasks working with chunks. I would also add an indexed property that is set to a unix timestamp in milliseconds with the id number in the decimal position. This will give you a very easy indexed field to serially march through you entities in either order. If you rely on multiple puts() and the DateProperty, you may have issues with date collisions.

Summary: Figure out a way to utilize a coding scheme for you entity ids that enable your sequencing, and use cron + pull queue. Utilize a timestamp field for ordering queries.

HTH, stevep

Comment: Thanks! N is less than 100. I did not know what pull queues were so I just had a look. Isn't this an overly complicated approach though? I imagined this would be much simpler..

Comment: If this is indeed worthwhile, do you mind if you explain a bit more on how to lease tasks and generate ids?

Comment: re: ids: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService#allocateIds(com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key,%20java.lang.String,%20long)

Comment: It is critical with GAE to think about how your code affects latency (time per response), and costs. The approach you suggested in the question involves indices, interval jumps in queries, and individual record handling. These are all a quantum step up in latency and costs versus a series of get_by_ids(). There is a very minor increase in complexity with the id-placeholder entity, but it is very minor. In total, though, it is only a few dozen lines of code at best.

Comment: Thank you! I'll do that.

Comment: @stevep so when you say generate new ids you mean like `post = Post(key_name='200')` ?

Comment: Mina, there are a number of ways to manage your own ids. It really depends on your strategy. if my model were named Project_Image, and I had 100 text_items to put() I would build my nib ids (note you use nab): idkey = 'project_image_%d' % (my_counter) then add to your list for the multiple put my_list.append(rec = Project_Image(id = idkey, ...))  HTH, hard to write code in comments, but from this point your really need to start studying the GAE tutorial a bit. stevep

Comment: Sorry autocorrect changed ndb to either nib or nab above, and my comment edit window closed.

Comment: Thanks again, I will have a look!

Answer (score 1):

- Option 1 involves 1 put, 1 query and 1 delete per new Post.
- Option 2 uses 1 put per new Post and one query + batch delete per day.
- Option 3 uses 1 put per new Post

In all cases you get the newest N posts using the same query, which could be memcached for performance (invalidate the cache when a new Post is added). Remember your query should order by time descending first, then get the first N results.

So assuming there is more than one new post per day, option 2 is more efficient than option 1 and should cost less.

Option 3 / not deleting posts is even more efficient (in terms of DB operations) and you may be interested to keep a history of older posts, but you'd pay for storage space - if you're not adding gigabytes per month then this is pretty small and may be your best option.

Comment: Thanks for that.. stevep's answer is more effecient so I'm going with that.